# Messages are not showing on frontend magento 2.1.7

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, luma-theme, global-messages

> This question might be asked here before. I have checked many threads
>   but couldn't find a solution for my problem. I have a custom Magento
>   2.1.7 theme. In my website the success/error messages not showing. Initially, I thought it would be the issue of my custom theme. **Then
>   I switched the design to default 'luma' theme. Now also the
>   success/error message not showing.** Can any one help me to sort it
>   out?

Edit *

I could find that message wrapper is loading, but the message texts are not fetching. I am here attaching the out put html of message wrapper

```
    <div class="page messages"><div data-placeholder="messages"></div>
<div data-bind="scope: 'messages'">
    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: cookieMessages, as: 'message' }" class="messages">
        <div data-bind="attr: {
            class: 'message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
            'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
        }">
            <div data-bind="html: message.text"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: messages().messages, as: 'message' }" class="messages">
        <div data-bind="attr: {
            class: 'message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
            'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
        }">
            <div data-bind="html: message.text"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                        "messages": {
                            "component": "Magento_Theme/js/view/messages"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: disable the full page cache in back end and check whether it's working or not

Comment: I have disabled the full page cache with command line and it was already disabled. Still couldn't get the messages.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw a similar issue in one of my Magento2 projects.

In my case, it turned out to be a custom module changing the functionality of setting and retrieving cookies in Magento.

Long story short... these messages are stored in a cookie called `mage-messages`

Then the message is retrieved and the cookie cleared as we can see here

```
 // vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js

 /**
 * Extends Component object by storage observable messages.
 */
initialize: function () {
    this._super();

    this.cookieMessages = _.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text');
    this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
        disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
    });

    // Force to clean obsolete messages
    if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
        customerData.set('messages', {});
    }

    $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
},
```

[image: mage-messages cookie]
I would recommend looking at this when debugging an issue related to these messages not showing.